# Scala Regex union

Tags: regex, scala

In Ruby, if I have two Regexps, I have the possibility to create another regexp like this:

```
a = /\d+/ # Matches digits
b = /\s+/ # Matches whitespaces
c = Regexp.union(a, b) # Matches sequences that consist only of digits or only of whitespaces
```

I want to do the same thing in Scala, but I didn't find out how I could do that. Note that I am not asking for a syntax to create a union of character classes like `(\d+)|(\s+)` in the previous example, I am really looking for a possibility to create a new Regexp from two given Regexps.

Actually, in the end, I will not do it for just two Regexps but a large number. I don't care about grouping or anything, I just want to know if a String matches one of a list of given Regexps. I could just check all of them in a loop, but that is too inefficient, that is why I need one Regexp to check the union.

Comment: If you want to match *this* OR *that*, you have to use the Alternation `|`.

Comment: If no `union`-like method exists in Scala, you could retrieve the pattern used by each regex and then combine them manually like `(regex1)|(regex2)`, and create a new regex from the result.

Comment: @stema Yes, I know, if I create the Regexps, then I use the |, but if I am already given two Regexps and I want to union them, I need something else.

Comment: @Vulcan Yes, that would be possible, but I think it gets a little more complicated because I have to take care of things like flags etc and it is kind of terrible, so I will only do that if I have no other choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scala uses the Java regex engine, which is based on the class `java.util.regex.Pattern`.  `Pattern` has exactly one method that can create a regex:

```
public static Pattern compile(String regex)
```

That's it, and Scala doesn't give you any relevant enhancements.

But one thing you can do is use the built-in unioning in match statements, here shown with capturing groups in case you want to pull something out of the string:

```
val Dig = """(\d+)""".r
val Wsp = """(\s+)""".r

scala> "45" match { case Dig(_) | Wsp(_) => println("found"); case _ => }
```

found

```
scala> "   " match { case Dig(_) | Wsp(_) => println("found"); case _ => }
```

found

If you really want a combined regex, you have to do it at the string level.  You can get the java `Pattern` from a Scala regex with `.pattern`, and another `.pattern` then gets the string.  Most regexes can be wrapped safely in `(?:)` to get a non-capturing block, so you can combine like so:

```
val Both = ("(?:"+Dig.pattern.pattern+")|(?:"+Wsp.pattern.pattern+")").r
```

However, any capturing groups inside will *both* be represented, but the non-used branch will be `null` (not exactly a good way to write idiomatic Scala, but anyway, this is what Java uses):

```
scala> "2" match { case Both(d,w) => if (w!=null) println("white") else println(d) }
2

scala> " " match { case Both(d,w) => if (w!=null) println("white") else println(d) }
white
```

Comment: Thanks, the version with Dig(_) | Wsp(_) does not actually work for my application, those were only examples, in my actual application, I have a long list of Regexps, so using several patterns would not be efficient. I guess I will probably do it with the your second solution, I only hoped that there is something less terrible similar to my Ruby example.

Comment: @Lykos - You can always write a method that puts pairs or sequences together.  For example, if `xs` is a collection of regexes, `xs.map(_.pattern.pattern).mkString("(?:", ")|(?:", ")").r` should be a regex of the whole bunch of them together

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine and reuse regex parts, I wrote [REL](https://github.com/Imaginatio/REL/) a library/DSL that does just that. Example usage for you case:

```
import fr.splayce.rel._
import Implicits._

val a: RE = "\\d+"
val b: RE = "\\s+"
val c: RE = a | b
```

`c` has a `r` method to get a Regex object. It is also in `Implicits`, so you can use it as a regex, say `c findAllIn someText`. It will automatically wrap `a` and `b` in non-capturing groups if needed.

If you have a collection of regexes, you can just do `reduceLeft`:

```
val regexes: List[RE] = List("a", "b", "c")
regexes.reduceLeft(_ | _)
```

On a side note:

- if you import `Symbols._`, you have short notations for things like `\d` and `\s`
- it implements most of your usual regex operations for maximum reusability

Thus, with REL, you can write the first example directly as:

```
val c = δ.+ | σ.+
```

It also provides ways to reuse and combine the associated extractors.

If you prefer vanilla scala, then I have nothing to add to Rex Kerr's answer.

Comment: Thanks, your library looks great. However, I am always a little reluctant to add a new dependency to another library to my project if I only use it at one single location, so I follow the other approach.

Comment: I understand, that's what I'd do too in your position. I'm mostly leaving this answer for other readers that may need a more complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

@akauppi if you want a list of regexes to match a given string you could do something like this:

```
val regexes = List("\\d+".r, "\\s+".r, "a".r)
val single  = s"(${regexes.mkString("|")})".r
"123" match {
  case single(_*) = println("match")
  case _ => println("no match")
}
// above prints: match

"123  " match {
  case single(_*) = println("match")
  case _ => println("no match")
}
// above prints: no match
```

The best way to utilize a list of regexes is to use regex notation. This is really the same as saying

```
val single = "(\\d+|\\s+|a)".r
```

Answer (score 0):

While these answers may work they might be a bit out dated or over complicated.

```
val reg1 = "\\d+".r
val reg2 = "\\s+".r
val reg3 = s"${reg1}{$reg2}".r
"123  " match { 
    case reg3(_*) => println("match")
    case _ => println("no match")
 }
```

Comment: Your code does not answer the current question: "I just want to know if a String matches one of a list of given Regexps"